# Pattern for updating Objects/Documents with Spring-Data MongoDB and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to come up with a reusable pattern for updating MongoDB Documents when using Spring Data in conjunction with Spring MVC.

The use case can generally be summarized by:

1. A document is created in Mongo using repository.save()
2. Parts of that document are then presented in a Spring MVC editable form.
3. A user submits updated parts of that document which are then saved.

If I use the repository.save() method in step 3, I will lose any data in the document that was not bound to the form.  Making the form responsible for the entire document is fragile so this is where it seems the findAndModify() method of the MongoTemplate comes in handy.

To use the findAndModify() method, I've created Form objects that support a toMap() method which takes the Form object's properties as a Map and removes some of the fields (e.g. class and id).  This gets me a Map that contains only the fields that I care about from the Form object.  Passing the object ID and this map to an update() method on my customized repository, I build Query and Update objects that I can pass to the findAndModify() method.

Using this approach, I'm able to add fields to my objects easily and only worry about instances when there are fields I don't want to update from a form posting.  Document fields not manipulated by the Form should be retained.  It still seems slightly convoluted to be using both the Repository and MongoTemplate so I'm wondering if there are better examples for how to handle this.  It seems like this should be a consistent pattern when working with Mongo and Spring MVC (at the least).

I've created a sample project showing how I achieve this model on GitHub.  The Spock Tests show how "updating" a Document using save() will blow away fields as expected and my update() method.

https://github.com/watchwithmike/diner-data

What are other people doing when dealing with partial updates to Documents using Spring MVC and Spring Data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking whatever the user supplies and just shoving that in the database you are running the risk of doing something dangerous like updating or creating data that they shouldn't be able to. Instead, you should first query Mongo to get the most recent version of the document, change any fields (it looks like you are using Groovy so you could loop through all the properties and set them on the new document), and then save the new, complete document.

If you are making small, consistent updates (like increasing the number of votes, or something like that), you could create a custom MongoDB query using the `MongoTemplate` to do an update to a few fields. Check out the `spring-data-mongodb` [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update) for more. You can also add custom methods to the `MongoRepository` that use the `MongoTemplate`.

Comment: The idea is to not take everything the user supplies and shove it into the database.  The only thing the user may supply are the data fields in the form.  For my simple example I had my Form extend my model object but that's not necessary.  I can also exclude "user supplied" fields in my toMap() method. The update() method I created in my custom repository does use the MongoTemplate to query and update but coming from JPA/Hibernate this seems like a bit more code than I expected and I'm wondering if there's a better way or if this is just a side effect of having greater flexibility with Mongo.

Comment: @watchwithmike were you able to solve this problem by any chance?

Comment: @VishwasShashidhar I ended up using the patterns you can find in the [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/) application which you can configure to use MongoDB. The [Creating an entity page)[https://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html] provides an overview of what the project does on the entity side, you'll just want to make sure you configure it to use MongoDB instead of JPA.  I just used JHipster as a reference rather than start my whole project from it. Hope that helps.